# How to identify a Failed transaction on 2checkout order response?

Tags: php, laravel-5, payment-gateway, recurring-billing, 2checkout

I am getting the same response for both success and fail transaction I am on a testing sandbox mode and using hosted checkout method and my order is recurring billing here is my response from 2checkout

```
'sid' => '101346602',
  'middle_initial' => '',
  'li_0_name' => 'Business_3_8.00',
  'key' => 'F22EBC18AB05AAC86905E706410FCF0F',
  'state' => 'AS',
  'email' => 'manash149@gmail.com',
  'li_0_type' => 'product',
  'li_0_duration' => 'Forever',
  'order_number' => '9093731870208',
  'lang' => 'en',
  'currency_code' => 'USD',
  'invoice_id' => '9093731870217',
  'li_0_price' => '8.00',
  'total' => '8.00',
  'credit_card_processed' => 'Y',
  'zip' => '781001',
  'li_0_quantity' => '1',
  'cart_weight' => '0',
  'fixed' => 'Y',
  '_token' => 'NK7YGNjpXem5pY7JK9VlYA1rT4cIqgY4EFrv8N81',
  'last_name' => '',
  'li_0_product_id' => '',
  'street_address' => 'asd',
  'city' => 'Guwahati',
  'li_0_tangible' => 'N',
  'li_0_description' => '',
  'ip_country' => 'India',
  'country' => 'IND',
  'merchant_order_id' => '',
  'demo' => 'Y',
  'pay_method' => 'CC',
      'cart_tangible' => 'N',
      'phone' => '9706353416 9706353416',
      'li_0_recurrence' => '1 Month',
      'street_address2' => '',
      'first_name' => 'Manash',
      'card_holder_name' => 'Manash',
```

Comment: https://www.2checkout.com/documentation/notifications/recurring-installment-failed check here for failed one getting message as "message_type => RECURRING_INSTALLMENT_FAILED"

Comment: But if you enter incorrect credit card number that is in test data I am using the declined card it is still accepting the sale/order so what needs to be done

Comment: I think that's related to the idea being test environment? They just accept any credit in order not to charge real credit cards. May be.

Answer (score 1):

Used this card for failed transactions

```
Credit Card Number: 4333433343334333
Expiration date: 10/2020
cvv:123
```

For more information Take a look at 
https://www.2checkout.com/documentation/libraries-php-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

The following card info will cause a failure in sandbox:

CC# 4333433343334333
MM / YYYY 10 / 2020
CVV 123

I just verified this myself, which test card data were you using?

Comment: what type of failure I mean how to identify based on the response? Please guide me.

Comment: If you're receiving a response, you're using a 'success' test card. If you use the above test card data above, you should receive an authorization failure or similar verbiage. You shouldn't actually see a response full of parameters (unless your app was designed to provide the payload or stored in logs) when the auth failure occurs.